# Firebase Messaging Service

Tags: android, firebase, xamarin, firebase-cloud-messaging

i am implementing fire-base messaging service to send notification to all users. Everything is fine till now, but issue is when i turn off my WiFi and at the same time send notification from fire-base console, status of my message shows that message has been sent successfully but when i turn on my WiFi i don't receive any notification, why is that so, does FCM not allow pending notifications or i am doing something wrong. Is their any implementation of how to send notifications which are in pending state. Below is my code

**Android-Manifest**

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" package="com.xamarin.fcmexample" android:versionCode="1" android:versionName="1.0" android:installLocation="auto">
    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="16" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
    <application android:label="FCMClient">
        <receiver android:name="com.google.firebase.iid.FirebaseInstanceIdInternalReceiver" android:exported="false" />
        <receiver android:name="com.google.firebase.iid.FirebaseInstanceIdReceiver" android:exported="true" android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
                <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION" />
                <category android:name="${applicationId}" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
    </application>
</manifest>
```

**FirebaseMessagingService.cs**

```
    public class MyFirebaseMessagingService : FirebaseMessagingService
{
    const string TAG = "MyFirebaseMsgService";
    public override void OnCreate()
    {
        base.OnCreate();
    }
    public override void OnMessageReceived(RemoteMessage message)
    {
        Log.Debug(TAG, "From: " + message.From);
        Log.Debug(TAG, "Notification Message Body: " + message.GetNotification().Body);
        SendNotification(message.GetNotification().Body);
    }
    void SendNotification(string messageBody)
    {
        var intent = new Intent(this, typeof(MainActivity));
        intent.AddFlags(ActivityFlags.ClearTop);
        var pendingIntent = PendingIntent.GetActivity(this, 0, intent, PendingIntentFlags.OneShot);

        var notificationBuilder = new Notification.Builder(this)
            .SetSmallIcon(Resource.Drawable.Icon)
            .SetContentTitle("FCM Message")
            .SetContentText(messageBody)
            .SetAutoCancel(true)
            .SetContentIntent(pendingIntent);

        var notificationManager = NotificationManager.FromContext(this);
        notificationManager.Notify(0, notificationBuilder.Build());
    }
}
```

**FirebaseIDService.cs**

```
   public class MyFirebaseIIDService : FirebaseInstanceIdService
    {
        const string TAG = "MyFirebaseIIDService";
        public override void OnTokenRefresh()
        {
            var refreshedToken = FirebaseInstanceId.Instance.Token;
            Log.Debug(TAG, "Refreshed token: " + refreshedToken);
            SendRegistrationToServer(refreshedToken);
        }
        void SendRegistrationToServer(string token)
        {
            // Add custom implementation, as needed.
        }
    }
```

Comment: I use the same code and try to reproduce your problem, the first time deployed on my phone , everything works fine. When I turn off WiFi,  although there is a brief delay , the app still received the message. But when I clean and rebuild the project, I cant receive any message.

Answer (score 0):

I assume your problem relies on whether the app is in the foreground or in the background and whether you are sending a **Notification** payload or a **Data** Payload because when the app is in the background a Notification payload will not reach the "OnMessageReceived" callback. Check the app state table in the following link: https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/android/receive